# Physical properties of transformers

Tags: transformer, theory

In class, we were given equations for the transformer in terms of number of turns primary/secondary and coupling coefficient K, however effect of distance between coils, presence/absence of core, and composition of core were not covered.

Of particular interest: What is the equation for 2 parallel straight wires? Clearly turn ratio is 1:1, but how to account for distance between the two?

Comment: They are very big and made from a special metal that can turn into a car.

Comment: I am so sorry..

Comment: Actually pretty funny

Comment: especially coming from robotics guy

Comment: If the two parallel straight wires are infinite in length and with zero thickness, the distance between the two doesn't matter at all, and therefore will not appear in any equation.

Comment: More than meets the eye.

Comment: Crossposted to phyisics.se

Comment: on physics.se @ http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24459/equations-governing-mutual-inductance-and-transformers

Answer (score 6):

### About the core

Consider an inductor, and the magnitic field that it generates:

[image]

it creates loops all around the windings, with a direction given by the direction of the current (see Ampère's law).

If you put two inductors close to each other, the changing <sup>*(Credits to Curd)*</sup> field generated by one will induce (sorry for the pun) a current in the other one, with the proportion given by the number of windings (because of *Faraday's law of induction*). But this coupling will be limited to the portion of the field which falls in the area of the second inductor, which can or cannot be a limited portion of the total.

Using a core, you *force* whe magnetic flux over a closed path, and the great part of it will follow that path:

[image]

This translates in a higher efficiency of the coupling, as almost all the magnetic field is induced in the secondary, as opposed to the previous case.

### What happens with two wires?

If you have a single ideal wire, it also generates a magnetic field, again described by Ampère's law:

[image]

Since this field is distributed through all the wire, it will be much weaker than using windings, because these have the effect to concentrate this field into the inner space (where is the core).

As for inductors, distance reduces the portion of the magnetic field that the wires share, and with it the power transferred. Note that with the core, in the ideal case in which all the flux is convoyed the distance doesn't matter, as all the flux is into the core.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, and clabaccio in particular, for the interesting info. I'm definitely far more comfortable with the physics now. However, couldn't I just get some equations? Pretty please?

Comment: Also, is fig. 2 any different from a bar core?

Comment: @JoeStavitsky If I understand what you mean, a bar core is not a closed loop, so it won't be the same. But I don't know anything more about that.

Comment: The sloppy formulation "the field generated by one will induce a current in the other one" should be more exactly
"the change of the field generated by one will induce a voltage in the other". U = d/dt Phi (Faraday's Law of Induction)

Comment: @Curd thanks! I was going a bit superficially, but your correction is right

Answer (score 3):

With no core, distance decreases the coupling inductance and increases the leakage inductance.  In the limiting case of two wires far apart, they each have only their inherent inductance, which is all leakage inductance if you view them together as a transformer.

In a perfect transformer, the leakage inductance is zero.  If you were to put a resistor accross the secondary, the primary would appear to be just that resistance divided by the square of the turns ratio.  For example, if you had a perfect 1:2 transformer and put 1 kΩ accross the secondary, the primary would look like a 250 Ω resistor and nothing else.

As coupling is decreased, such as by increasing distance, more of the primary's impedance comes from leakage inductance and the series component that is the resistor accross the secondary reflected to the primary gets less and less.  Eventually at no coupling you have only the leakage inductance, which is the primary acting as a stand-alone inductor.

Comment: Sorry, what is leakage inductance? Also, what does the core do, and what effect does composition of the core have?

Comment: @Joe: Leakage inductance is the part of the windings inductance that is not coupled to other windings.  It represents the magnetic field "private" to a winding such that it does not induce voltage or current in other windings.  You can model a real transformer in part as a ideal transformer with leakage inductance in series with each winding.

Comment: ah, got it, now how about equation for distance vs mutual inductance? Also, cores?Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Imagine 2 water hoses.

One with water pointed to another hose to catch the water.

Without efficient coupling, you have a leaky hose and none is transferred.
In that case the primary impedance is just that of the primary hose.

Knowing you are an engineering student with a brilliant imagination, and you know how iron filings collect around a wire to show the magnetic flux, you need to use laminated iron steel to couple the high power low frequency power to the secondary wire, or a ceramic ferrite core for higher frequencies that have smaller size and less loss than iron.  The higher the F, the lower the permeability that can be used to become low loss.

But 50/60Hz can use big fat hoses or  high µ magnetic common cores to join the primary secondary wires.

There are many shapes and sizes depending on whether you need a fire hose or a garden hose or a sewer hose.

But if you own a soldering gun, you have a transformer with many primary turns and only 1 secondary turn that will heat the heavy copper tip enough to melt solder in a second.

Now if this analogy is not clear, you could  be a programmer. ;)

Comment: Sorry, too obscure for me. Formulae please!

Comment: I assume you have done your basic homework. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_coupling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#Induction_law http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_inductance#Coupled_inductors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance/derivation_of_self_inductance

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @madrivereric has correctly mentioned, I have the following to add:

Because I didn't like the units very much, I have tried to verify the formula - directly at the source and elsewhere. Unfortunately, the book by Frederick Grover isn't freely available (copyright still valid on later editions), but I've found early bulettins of the U.S. Bureau of Standards published in 1908 and 1916, co-authored by Frederick Grover and Edward Rosa. In those publications, the formula appears in the following form:

[image: Mutual inductance of parallel wires, original formula by E.Rosa]

Curiously to me, in those magnificent bulettins that were well over 200 pages long, containing a fine collection of formulas, the authors hardly ever mentioned the *units* to use for input and output... except casually in some examples, but not strictly for every formula.
It is not surprising that they did not stick to standard SI units, as the international SI system only got agreed upon several decades later :-)
Know ye, that the l and d dimensions are in centimeters, and the mutual inductance M is in *nanoHenry* !

I like E.Rosa's compact form, without excessive use of fractions. By comparison to the form quoted by @madrivereric above, and to [another modern paper (a master's thesis)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ajay-Venkateswaran/publication/30010166_Analysis_of_planar_EBG_structures_using_transmission_line_models/links/556f2d8208aefcb861dd5086/Analysis-of-planar-EBG-structures-using-transmission-line-models.pdf?origin=publication_detail) where this formula is also quoted, I can see that where E.Rosa writes "log", he actually means "ln". Also, to re-base the formula to SI units, the leading "2" can be modified to read \$\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi}\$, which happens to be equal to \$2\cdot10^{-7}\$ because, as I've found out today :-) , \$\mu_0 = 4 \pi \cdot 10^{-7}\$ . So if I fit it all together, I get:

[image: Mutual inductance of parallel wires, my rehash]

What you get is the "mutual inductance" of two parallel wires. What use is that? You can plug that into the formula of a "coupling coefficient": \$k = \frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1 L_2}}\$ or, if both wires have the same self-inductance, even just \$k = \frac{M}{L}\$ . The two parallel wires work as a non-ideal transformer.
In that context, it is interesting to note that the formula for self-inductance of a straight wire is pretty similar to the mutual inductance:

[image: Self inductance of a straight wire, in SI units]

...where \$\rho\$ is the radius (not diameter!) of a wire thickness...

Once I put this all together, I was amazed that the coupling coefficient is actually pretty high - for many scenarios, some double digit per cent.

I'm studying / trying to approach basic physics of a lightning protection system, with some signal downlinks that have to come from the roof and remain protected. This set of formulas gives me a rough idea, how much EM coupling there is, between the lightning protection down-conductors and my communication cabling. The interesting question is, what to make of it. The two parallel wires work like a (non-ideal) 1:1 transformer. If the two wires are the same length, you should never get a higher voltage induced at the secondary, than what the primary faces. It's down to \$\Delta\Phi/\Delta t\$, and by extension \$\Delta I/\Delta t\$ etc. Beware of making loops on your signal cables. And this answer opens a number of other questions in my context... what to ground where and whatnot. Yes I know what the IEC62305 norm says. My interest in the basic physics is academic. It is fun :-)

Comment: "as a lossy transformer" -- perhaps you meant "as a nonideal transformer"?

Comment: @Tim Williams : you're right... it's not lossy as in "turning a part of the energy into heat". Perhaps "loosely coupled" would be a better description?

Comment: "Loose" implies small k, but for k = M/L, and l >> (rho, d), k = (ln (2l/d) - 1) / (ln (2l/d) - 3/4), and for ln l >> 1, k --> 1. A nonideal transformer captures all variables in play: resistance (loss) is absent from the problem, nor is it embedded within a system (in which case we would prefer to specify type i.e. insertion/return loss), and only the three (two self and one mutual) inductances are present, as in the linear nonideal transformer.

Comment: Okay, gonna edit my text, thanks for educating me :-)

Answer (score 1):

From Grover's *Inductance Calculations Working Formulas and Tables*, pg 31, the mutual (coupling) inductance betwen two equal parallel straight filaments is

\$M=0.002l \left[log_e\left(\frac{l}{d} + \sqrt{1 + \frac{l^2}{d^2}} \right)- \sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}{l^2}} + \frac{d}{l}\right]\$

\$l\$ is the length of the wire and \$d\$ is the distance between the wires.

In this expression the dimensions \$l\$ and \$d\$ are centimeters and the inductance is microhenrys.

Comment: That was spot on, you have answered my question. I've been searching in vain for an answer for about half an hour. Also, thanks for pointing me to Grover and Rosa. It's been over a hundred years since their first publications... Never mind the decade between our respective messages :-)